# Function to Replace org-links with Abbreviations

Tags: org-mode

As suggested by the [Org-mode Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Link-abbreviations.html), I've customized `org-link-abbrev-alist` as follows:

```
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist
       '(;; Abbreviations for websites
         ("google"         . "https://www.google.com/#q=")
         ("github"         . "https://www.github.com/")))
```

This is convenient because I can easily insert a link with:

```
[[google:cat pictures][Google Search for cat pictures]]
```

This is useful because if the URL changes, I can just updated `org-link-abbrev-alist`. However, there are instances in the past where I've used the entire non-abbreviated link or decided, after visiting a website enough times, to create an abbreviation.

How would I write a function to use `org-link-abbrev-alist` to turn long form links in all org-mode files (say, all files in `org-agenda-files` to abbreviated links? For example,

```
[[https://www.google.com/#q=cat pictures][Google search for cat pictures]]
```

to:

```
[[google:cat pictures][Google search for cat pictures]]
```

I'd also like to integrate this function with `org-mode-hook` so that it happens automatically on either save or startup.

Lastly, I'd also like a function that does the reverse and replaces the abbreviation with the long form link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of research, I encountered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682079/batch-replace-a-bunch-of-strings-in-a-text-file-with-emacs) and adopted it to answer my question above. The following function and hook will replace all links in an org-mode file with their corresponding abbreviations on save.

```
;; Create abbreviations
(defun my/create-org-link-abbreviations ()
  "Replace all long form links in current file with their corresponding abbreviations in `org-link-abbrev-alist'."
  (interactive)
  (dolist (pair org-link-abbrev-alist)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward (concat "[[" (cdr pair)) nil t)
        (replace-match (concat "[[" (car pair) ":"))))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-to-list 'write-file-functions 'my/create-org-link-abbreviations)))

;; Remove abbreviations
(defun my/remove-org-link-abbreviations ()
  "Replace all link abbreviations in current file with their long form counterparts in `org-link-abbrev-alist'."
  (interactive)
  (dolist (pair org-link-abbrev-alist)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward (concat "[[" (car pair) ":") nil t)
        (replace-match (concat "[[" (cdr pair)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks @npostavs, I've update the answer to reflect your comment.